# How do I open and close a connection to a database(.db) Data Connection held within Server Explorer using C# code within Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, odbc, sqlanywhere

[Server Explorer closed connection reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPEcY.png)

[Closed connection properties reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyad4.png)

The code that follows is the data access layer for the application that is being written. The code has two methods making two connection attempts, using `OdbcConnection` and `OdbcDataAdapter`, to a .db database file that is set in a local file path and brought into the Visual Studio Server Explorer Data Connections:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Data.DataAccess
{
    public class PatientDatabase
    {
        public OdbcDataAdapter ConnectAndCreateDataAdapter()
        {
            string selectCommand = "select * from patient";

            var connectionString = "Driver={SQL Anywhere 10};DBN=Training1;UID=dba;PWD=sql;Data Source=C:\\Projects\\Training\\Training1.4.2\\Training1.db;";

            OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();

            var dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);

            return dataAdapter;
        }

        public void ConnectAndPopulateDataGridView(DataGridView dataGridView)
        {
            BindingSource patientBindingSourceTest = new BindingSource();
            dataGridView.DataSource = patientBindingSourceTest;

            string selectCommand = "SELECT patient.first_name + ' ' + patient.last_name as patient_name, patient.patient_id, patient.address, patient.city, patient.state, patient.zipcode, patient.phone, patient.notes, patient.classification_id, patient_classification.description from patient, patient_classification right join patient on patient.classification_id = patient_classification.patient_classification_id";

            var connectionString = "Driver={SQL Anywhere 10};DBN=Training1;UID=dba;PWD=sql;Data Source=C:\\Projects\\Training\\Training1.4.2\\Training1.db;";

            OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();

            var dataSet = new DataSet();

            var dataAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);

            DataTableMapping patientTableMapping = new DataTableMapping("Table", "patient");
            dataAdapter.TableMappings.Add(patientTableMapping);
            patientTableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add(new DataColumnMapping("patient_id", "Patient ID"));
            patientTableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add(new DataColumnMapping("patient_name", "Patient Name"));
            patientTableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add(new DataColumnMapping("address", "Address"));
            patientTableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add(new DataColumnMapping("city", "City"));
            patientTableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add(new DataColumnMapping("state", "State"));
            patientTableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add(new DataColumnMapping("zipcode", "Zip Code"));
            patientTableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add(new DataColumnMapping("phone", "Phone"));
            patientTableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add(new DataColumnMapping("notes", "Notes"));
            patientTableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add(new DataColumnMapping("classification_id", "Classification ID"));
            patientTableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add(new DataColumnMapping("description", "Classification"));

            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

            patientBindingSourceTest.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["patient"].DefaultView;

            dataGridView.Columns["Notes"].Visible = false;
            dataGridView.Columns["Patient ID"].Visible = false;
            dataGridView.Columns["Classification ID"].Visible = false;

            var commandBuilder = new OdbcCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

            dataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the thing is, this code works and functions quite nicely... but..

the Data Connection (database) starts off closed when opening the solution. The image links above show what I am referring to.

The problem with that is my code does not work unless that connection is "Open"

`connection.Open();` doesn't open that connection even though they have the same connection string when created. Opening the connection consists of a manual right click of the database listed in the Data Connections and clicking "Refresh"

So...

Is there any way that this right click can be done via code? Can I open the connection like I would be doing if I were to connect to say... SQL Server? Otherwise, what happens when I compile and publish the code? Does the database stay built within the application and responds to the code `connection.Open();` or when a `DataAdapter` opens a connection?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to put the database file in the bin\debug of the starting project folder and change the connection path to "DBF=Training1.db;UID=dba;PWD=sql", my bad. Sorry it took so long to actually post the answer after I'd solved it.